# Best way to keep an array of Node Cron jobs running in memory

Tags: arrays, cron

I need to keep an array of cron jobs in memory that run according to configuration specifics. Presently I am initializing the array of cron jobs a by getting the config data as records from a datastore. Then I traverse the records, create a cron job based on the information in each record. Once a cron job is created, it is stored in memory in a script level array.

Here is the code that does the work.

```
const arrCronJobs = [];

function populateEnvVarCronJobs() {
  console.log('populating crons');
  return dataHelper.getCronJobs()
    .then((results) => {
        // Task entities found.
        const jobs = results[0];
        jobs.forEach((job) => {
            const rtn = configCron(job);
            if (rtn) {
                console.log(`adding job: ${rtn}`);
                arrCronJobs.push(rtn);
            }
        });
        return arrCronJobs;
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });}

//initialize the array of Cron jobs

populateEnvVarCronJobs()
.then(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

The way I keep the whole thing running memory is to create an HTTP server that just keeps listening away.

```
const server = http.createServer( function(req, res) {
/* Listener handler behavior...... */});

server.listen(port);
```

My question is this: Is using a HTTP server the best way to keep the array of Cron jobs active in memory? Or is there some inherent risk that I am not seeing that dictates it will be better for me to take another approach?

Thanks in advance. I look forward to reading thoughtful responses.

Answer (score 0):

The only real problem is you are exposing your node app at the port (and using that port) for no real reason. For security, never listen on a port arbitrarily, it opens you up to exploits.

using a package like [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) would be more appropriate, you can also use the package [ontime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ontime)  to schedule jobs in a cron like fashion.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is great! Thank you!